# setListAdapter doesn't call getView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I've tried to refactor some code.. but now when I call setListAdapter() inside my fragment, it doesn't call the getView of the class loading the right view. I've even tried to use some custom adapter to make some test, but it doesn't log anything...

Any idea? Thanks! :)

```
      setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(){

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                            Log.i("LOG", "TEST");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is with the data which you are passing to the Adapter. if that array is empty or the size is 0 then getView will not get called.

Please check that from debugging the code or else give some static data for initial check

Comment: Good..support is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If your adapter has item count=0 then it won't create any views.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
}
```

getCount must return number greater than 0 for list to call getView, and display view.